# Build bigsparser::SFBM matrix iteratively

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, sparse-file

I wish to build a matrix with `10^7` columns and `2500` rows. Since this is too large for my computer, I thought I could create the matrix iteratively. I would like to use the `bigsparser` package for storing the matrix on disk.

Here is how I create the first matrix:

```
library(bigsparser)
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
nvars <- 10000000  # columns
ncons <- 10        # rows
n_nonzero <- round(0.02*nvars*ncons) # approximate, there may be actually less values
set.seed(13)

# the first table
Amat <- data.frame(
    i=sample.int(ncons, n_nonzero, replace=TRUE),
    j=sample.int(nvars, n_nonzero, replace=TRUE),
    x=runif(n_nonzero)
)
setDT(Amat)
Amat <- unique(Amat, by=c("i", "j"))
AmatSparse <- sparseMatrix(
    i=Amat[,get("i")], j=Amat[,get("j")], x=Amat[,get("x")],
    dims=c(2500, 10^7L)
)
AmatSFBM <- as_SFBM(AmatSparse, backingfile="sparsemat", compact = FALSE)
```

As you can see, I know the dimensions of the final matrix beforehand and have set it accordingly.

Now I want to add some rows, like that:

```
for (iter in 2:250) {
    Amat <- data.frame(
        i=sample.int(ncons, n_nonzero, replace=TRUE),
        j=sample.int(nvars, n_nonzero, replace=TRUE),
        x=runif(n_nonzero)
    )
    setDT(Amat)
    Amat <- unique(Amat, by=c("i", "j"))
    Amat[,i:=i+(iter-1)*500]

    # this does not work:
    AmatSFBM[Amat[,get("i")], Amat[,get("j")]] <- Amat[,get("x")]
}
```

However, the `]<-` operator seems not to work for `SFBM` objects.

Is there any way to build a `SFBM` object other than `as_SFBM` from a sparse matrix? For example,

- can I add two SFBM objects of the same dimensions
- can I create a SFBM object from a CSV file or similar?

Both would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SFBM` class has a method `$add_columns()⁠` which you can use to iteratively grow your matrix. Generally, when you are memory constrained, it is a good idea to avoid unnecessary intermediate assignments. In the following piece of code I first write a function to generate the component sparse matrices. Then I create a starting matrix and finally iteratively add the component matrices. I've limited it to `9` iterations for this example, but you can just set it to `249` to get your full matrix.

```r
library(bigsparser)
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)

set.seed(13)

# Function to generate component matrix
generate_sparse_mat <- \(nrow = 2500, ncol = 40000, n_nonzero = round(0.02*nrow*ncol)) {
  data.table(
    i = sample.int(nrow, n_nonzero, replace = TRUE),
    j = sample.int(ncol, n_nonzero, replace = TRUE),
    x = runif(n_nonzero)
  ) |>
    unique(by = c("i", "j")) |>
    as.list() |>
    c(dims = list(c(nrow, ncol))) |>
    do.call(what = sparseMatrix)
}

# Starting matrix
mat <- generate_sparse_mat() |> 
  as_SFBM(compact = FALSE)

# Iteratively add colums
for (k in seq_len(9)) mat$add_columns(generate_sparse_mat(), offset_i = 0)

mat
#> A Sparse Filebacked Big Matrix with 2500 rows and 400000 columns.
```

Comment: That‘s good, thanks for pointing out the ˋadd_columnsˋ method! But I would need to grow the rows, not the columns. Maybe ˋt()ˋ works in my case, will try tomorrow.

Comment: Clever use of ˋdo.callˋ, too!

Comment: Works perfectly. Using `cprodVec`, it is possible to perform `t(A) %*% b` matrix multiplications. I learned a lot today.